# Installing .net with low space on C

Tags: windows-xp, .net-framework

i have to install .NET 4 on some PCs here at work to run the current version of our program. The problem is that one of the PCs only has 500MB free space on the C Drive and .NET 4 requires 850MB and since it's a very small partition we couldn't find anything to remove.

The PC has lots of space on D and E, so is there any way to make .NET install on another partition?

TEMP is already directed to E:\Temp, so it's not just the temporary files that require so much space.

(A simple and fast (in terms of work time) solution would be very much preferred as the PC is used for quite important work that can't be stopped too long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET has to install into the windows system folder as far as I know.  Is it not possible (and easier) to move some of the other programs to the other partitions?  You said you couldn't remove anything, but can you **move** anything?

Comment: We tried but the harddrive is far too small. I'll accept this because sadly it gives the correct answer: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Sorry it's not something that can be fixed!

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about installing .NET on another partition, but you could move the pagefile off the C drive onto either D or E? This should free you up some space on C - see this [KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307886).

Comment: Good suggestion, but after checking the pagefile is already on another drive.

Answer (score 4):

What about using symlinks? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link

You could have the .NET folder in C:/Windows point to a "real" folder on one of the other drives. Maybe not the prettiest solution, but probably the fastest.

Answer (score -1):

As soon as I know, .Net is installing stuff into your windows folder. So, you could either move the pagefile or you use a partitioning tool (after full backup) to merge some of the free space with C so you can install it.

Comment: -1 - Merging drives is a REALLY bad idea.  If you have a hardware failure on one, you lost the contents of both.

Comment: Thats why I added the "(after full backup) you never should do something like that without a full backup and possible replacement hardware... thought that would be clear...

Answer (score -1):

How much RAM has the computer?
Move your paging file to another drive, leaving 2 MB for basic debugging.  This might even speed up performance.
Check if hibernation is enabled and disable it in the power settings.
If you can combine these two, you should be able to free enough space for the installation