# Running out of space installing .Net Framwork on a thin client

Tags: windows, disk-space, .net-framework, thin-client, usb-flash-drive

I'm providing this as a new Question and answer because the tags on this [older thread](https://superuser.com/questions/183422/installing-net-with-low-space-on-c) don't include some more generic tags that I searched on when looking for a solution. This should work for all versions of .Net and versions of Windows. It won't make a particular version of .Net install on version it wouldn't otherwise work on.

I was having trouble installing 4.6.1 on a HP Thin client. There was about 500mb free on the 2G DOM. The Offline Installer was running out of space when verifying the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I was upgrading a HP T5740e 2G/2G from 4.0 to 4.6.1 so some of my steps are particular to the thin client environment.  This method moves the installer files to one thumb drive and verifies them to another so you are not using up the severely limited space on your DOM while trying to install to it.

### Setup

*(Can be done on any computer)*

1. ***Create a /Temp directory*** On a thumb drive with at least 800 MB free create a `D:\Temp` directory.

   This is where the still compressed image files in `e:\download` will be extracted for verification prior to installation.
2. ***Capture the needed .Net installer files.***
   To capture the .Net setup files you will need to use a command prompt in the directory of the .Net Offline Installer. Launch the installer with `/?` as the option. After it extracts everything to `C:\<random numbers and letters>`, it will pop up a window with all of the command line options for the installer. Leave this window open, open explorer and copy `C:\<random numbers and letters>` over to the Installer thumb drive (E:)  and rename to something sane - I used `E:\download`. If you don’t know what options you'll need, then take a screen shot of this window and press OK to close it. When it closes C:\ will be removed from the active boot drive so you must copy before closing.
3. ***Create Install461.bat in E:\download***

   > @echo off
   >
   > e:\download\Setup.exe /log e:\Active-try\ /parameterfolder e:\download\ /x86 /x64 /redist

There are options in use which tell it where to locate the setup files are: E:\download and where to put the logs:  E:\active-try. You will only want to use the next options which apply to your system for a smaller install: `/x86 /x64 /redist`. I was on a 32bit system so I just specified `/x86 /redist`.  There is a '/q' option for a quiet install which I am not using for instance.

### If you haven't already done so uninstall the previous version of .Net.

I was removing 4.0 here.

4. Uninstalled .net 4 extended
5. Uninstalled .net 4 core

### Write configuration to DOM and reboot

After the reboot, you will see the true amount of disk free, which occurs when the uninstaller cleans up after the reboot.

### Install the USB drives created during Setup.

6. ***Install two flash drives*** The drive with \Temp should be installed first.

   > First Drive - D: contains /TEMP and has at least 800M of free space
   >       You don't want to have /TEMP on the same drive as the install source unless you want an install that takes a long time. Temp needs to be large enough to expand the still compressed components for verification
   >
   > Second Drive - E: Contains /download which has the extracted .Net 4.6.1 install from the setup 
   >   This is done so the approximately 270M installer doesn't take up useful space on the DOM while you are trying to install it.
7. Right click "Computer" select `Properties`, then choose `Advanced Settings...`
   Click on `Environment Variables...` button
       Edit TEMP & TMP entries for User & System to point at `D:\Temp`

   > NOTE1: Make a note of where the setting is pointing (usually the Z: Ramdisk on HP Thin Clients) so that you can set it back afterwards.
   >
   > NOTE2: I'm not sure which set of Environment variables the installer uses to determine the TEMP to use so I set them all. The Thin client Ram Disk (Z:) is too small to deal with expanding and verifying the image files during setup and it causes a stuck state that the system can't recover from quickly. This is the reason we use a USB drive to perform this function.

### Verify and Install

8. Open an Administrator:Command Prompt
9. Change directory to `e:\download`
10. Type 'set' to verify that `TEMP=D:\Temp` & `TMP=D:\Temp`
11. type `install461.bat`

### After the Install Completes

12. Copy the verification log from D:\TEMP and the install log from E:\active-try into a new folder on `E:\` if you are going to be testing different options for the install or need to capture the install log for review.
13. Remove the thumb drives
14. Reset the TEMP and TMP environment variables changed in Step 7 to point at where they were before.
15. Write changes to DOM and reboot.
16. Test that your .Net applications all work as expected.
17. After the reboot you may want to commit the DOM changes one more time if you suspect that the reboot did file cleanup and you don't want to incur that DOM change and reset at every boot.